# Detect missing label in Prometheus by comparing it to yesterday

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I have a long list of devices in Prometheus and I'm looking for a way to set alert which will show which exact device is missing.

The metric (simplified) looks like that:

```
device{name="server1"}
device{name="server2"}
etc
```

A query like that will indicate that there is/are missing device(s):

```
count(device) - count(device offset 1d)
```

However then I will have to manually go through them to find which one is missing exactly. Is there a way to compare the "name" labels and show the missing ones in alert?

Answer (score 1):

You can try experimenting with something like:

```
device{} offset 1d unless device{}
```

This will return all timeseries in `device` metric 1d ago, where there is no counterpart right now. You can then alert on individual devices if needed.
Or it this is the preference you can alert on count(...) > 0 on the above and then use the fact that Prometheus supports executing queries in the templates for alert labels/annotations and put a list of devices in (for example) `description` annotation (or whichever annotation the receiver of alerts uses). This is shown in [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/template_examples/#advanced-iteration)

Comment: Thanks! I found a way to get the alert I need by using the `unless` statement and a bit of bodge to make it work correctly on my setup. Unfortunately, I cannot upvote you since I don't have enough reputation, but your solution works.